# Before insert trigger List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I want with this before insert trigger to get for the first the last OBJ__c created for my Account(Compte__c) and put the value in the field (Last__c ) and also get the other information (Compte__r.Station_Type__c , Compte__r.Type__c,Compte__r.Segmentation__c ) and put the value of each one of them in the field of the Obj__c (Type_Station__c  , Type1__c  , Segmentation_station__c )

I want that : the value of  Compte__r.Station_Type__c go to Type_Station__c   , and the same for the others .

But I get this error in the debug 'List has no rows for assignment to SObject   '.

How Can I solve this problem .

```
trigger BeforeInsert on Obj__c(before insert) {
    
     Id currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
    Date newDate = Date.today();
    Id currentUserProfileId = userinfo.getProfileId();
    String profileName = [SELECT Name FROM Profile WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()].Name;
    
    List<Obj__c> InsertList = new List<Obj__c>();
    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
    
    for(Obj__c objj : InsertList ){
        ids.add(objj.Compte__c);
    }
    
    Obj__c N = [Select id,CreatedDate from Obj__c where Compte__c IN:ids order by CreatedDate DESC Nulls Last Limit 1];
    
     Obj__c N1 = [Select id, Compte__r.Station_Type__c , Compte__r.Type__c,Compte__r.Segmentation__c 
                        from Obj__c where Compte__c IN:ids];

         for(Obj__c  obj : trigger.new) 
       {  
            

           obj.Last__c = N.id;

           obj.Type_Station__c = N1.Compte__r.Station_Type__c;

           obj.Type1__c = N1.Compte__r.Type__c;

           obj.Segmentation_station__c = N1.Compte__r.Segmentation__c  ;


            InsertList .add(obj);
                 
                upsert InsertList ;
           
       }
         
     
                

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an empty List in your code:

```
List<Obj__c> InsertList = new List<Obj__c>();
    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
    
    for(Obj__c objj : InsertList ){
        ids.add(objj.Compte__c);
    }
```

InsertList is empty and therefore your set ids is also empty
There fore your soql have no results

```
Obj__c N = [Select id,CreatedDate from Obj__c where Compte__c IN:ids order by CreatedDate DESC Nulls Last Limit 1];

 Obj__c N1 = [Select id, Compte__r.Station_Type__c , Compte__r.Type__c,Compte__r.Segmentation__c 
                    from Obj__c where Compte__c IN:ids];
```

If you are expecting multiple results from a query you need to assign it to a list like:

```
List<Obj__c> n1List = [Select id, Compte__r.Station_Type__c , Compte__r.Type__c,Compte__r.Segmentation__c 
                from Obj__c where Compte__c IN:ids];
```

Your are already in the Obj__c before Trigger so no need to call update a List of object from the same type. You can just assign a value. It will be saved.
When updating record out of this context you have to do it in the after update

I think what you are looking for has to be done in the compte__c trigger

Comment: I don't used the list because I don't need a multiple results , I want to get just one value for each field . I don't now if in also this case I should use a list , but I will trie your proposition .

Comment: when I used the list I get error the value Compte__r don't exist .

Comment: If you expect just one result your query need a selection by id or a Limit 1.
But when doing that you need to be sure that there will be a result. In your case there was non so assigning to obj__c is failing.
If Compte__r does not exist then something with your relation between both object is not correct. does compe__c has a lookuo to Obj__c? Or Master detail? Please share your schema

Comment: Yes it have a master detail .so even If I use limit 1  I will get the result .In the Obj__c N I used in my query Limit 1

Comment: What is the Master object?

Comment: I used in the Obj__c a master detail relation with compe__c.

Comment: Then you need to change your query.
 Compte__r works just for child object in your case the compe__c
So in your query you have to use FROM compte__c when you you want to user compte__r.

Comment: I don't understand your proposition very will . could you please be more clear

Comment: when doinig this:

Comment: I think there is no field compte__c  in your Obj__c. I think it is the other way around in your Object compte__c you have a field Obj__c and there you can user Obj__r.

Comment: in Obj__c I have a field his api name is compte__c  and it is a master detail with the compte__c  that why I used the select compte__r. from Obj__c

Comment: Please go to your developer console and select the query Editor. Type in your query and check your results first. Share your results.

Comment: I used the query in the editor `Select id,CreatedDate from Obj__c where Compte__c ='0011q0000150OBeAAM' order by CreatedDate DESC Nulls Last Limit 1`